Why if I spoof the position with GNSS Analysis MATLAB Google code,I get a spike of horizontal speed but it continue to be active while should be const
I'm using this GNSS Analysis Matlab Google code
to analyze the measurements performed via GNSSLogger app.
I was initially in Palermo,Sicily and tried to spoof to Rome. I get this



Horizontal speed when spoofing is activated get a spike, and that's ok since I'm moving from Palermo to Rome, but after that it continues to be activated, oscillating. But why? Shouldn't it come back to 0 since the position "remains" in Rome(?)
